# Want to add a message from sql database in jquery notification

Tags: jquery, sql

Here i am showing a notification in main page where it shows a jquery notification for insurance expiry date...actually i want to add the expiry date also with the message which is returned from database.

here my notification script for jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function test1() {
              $(document).ready(function() {
              $.sticky('Your insurance Expire on' );
              });
          }
    </script>
```

in main page aspx.cs am retrieving the date and displaying it on label same like i want in notification how i can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the database data into a hidden field on the page, and then have the jQuery pick up the text from the hidden field, such as

```
$.sticky('Your insurance expires on ' + $('#dateExpiryField').val());
```

Or something similar!

Comment: Actually i have the date and data in a label which is getting from database.As per your answer what i want to do..i hav done like this  <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value="lblissuranceexpiry.text" runat="server" /> and i add the id like your code but it doesnt work..how i will retrieve value to a hiddenfield